# React router create shortcut on home screen

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, react-router, shortcut-file

I have a react-based web app with router and URL parameters structure.
I want to create a shortcut of one of the page of website (webapp) on home screen my android
For example i want to shortcut reactive-cafe.web.app/waiter?id=7

So I go to

> chrome -> MyURL -> Add to home screen

But when I click the icon on home screen it redirects me on root

> reactive-cafe.web.app/

How can I fix this?
I need a shortcut on "/waiter?id=7 " but it shortcut opens on " /"

In manifest.json I have

```
 "start_url": ".",
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there any logic in your app that would trigger a redirect to the home `"/"` path? Can you edit the post to include a [mcve]?